# Wikipedia Edits History: how to split edit history and comments

Tags: dataset, data-acquisition

I am trying to import Wikipedia Edit History. The code that I am using is the following:

```
 WikipediaComment = 
      Map[Last, 
       StringSplit[
        Rest@StringSplit[
          Import["https://it.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stephen_Wolfram&action=history"], "(corr|prec)"], ". ."]];

WikipediaCommentNew = 
 Reverse[Most[
   StringTrim /@ (Map[
      StringReplace[#, 
        "(annulla)" | "(" | ")" | "\[RightArrow]" | "\[LeftArrow]" -> 
         ""] &, WikipediaComment])]]
```

But it does not work. What I would like to do is splitting date and comments, creating an association between them, in order to plot them separately and try to do some sentiment analysis.

Also this part seems not working:

```
WikipediaDate = 
 Map[Take[#, 1] &, 
  StringSplit[StringSplit[Import["https://it.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stephen_Wolfram&&\offset=&limit=455&action=history"], "( corr | prec )"],  ". . "]]

WikipediaDateList = 
 Reverse[Interpreter[
    "Date"][(StringRiffle /@ (((StringSplit /@ WikipediaDate)[[All, 
          All, {2, 3, 4}]])[[All, 1]]))]]
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Remove `Rest` from the first code block and `Most` from the second?

Comment: thanks kglr. Now it works, but the second part of the code (I just added in the post) does not work. This part should help me to extract information about the date of edits